# Windows XP - Can't disable Internet Options on menu bar

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

Users are tampering with browser/internet settings. I have disabled internet options on the menu bar for PCs with Windows 7 but can't achieve the same with Windows XP.

The command I'm using is

```
gpedit.msc
```

then on Local Group Policy Editor under

```
User Config -> Administrative templates -> Windows Components
```

I select `Internet Explorer`, but on XP its not even there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that it's not enabled.

You can (re)enable it with the following:

1. Right click on `Administrative Templates`
2. Click `Add/Remove Templates`
3. Add the `inetres` template (`inetres.adm`). You should find 
   the template in `%systemroot%\system32\GroupPolicy\Adm`.

**B.T.W.**: Gpedit is not available in Windows XP Home Edition. It's
only available in Windows XP Professional.

For advanced use only: to enable it on Windows XP Home you can [follow this guide](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/11/15/windows-xp-he-home-edition-gpedit-msc-group-policy-editing-via-registry.html)
Or for the less advanced: you can try [Doug's Security Console](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/utils/xp_securityconsole.htm)

Comment: Glad i could help! Please remember to accept an answer if you found it helpful. You can click the big checkbox left of an answer to accept it.